# Catch multiple exceptions

Tags: c++, exception, try-catch

How can I `catch` more than one exceptions at once?

I mean, I have to do A if I get `std::out_of_range` or `std::invalid_argument` or B if I get `std::runtime_error` or `std::bad_alloc`

It is an example... There are some cases in which I have more than 5 exceptions that bring me to the same point.

I just hope I don't have to copy-paste the same code multiple times!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't copy'n'paste, you put code in functions and call the function in multiple cases.

Here's how:

```
try {
    /* Stuff */
} catch (const std::out_of_range&) {
    do_A();
} catch (const std::invalid_argument&) {
    do_A();
} catch (const std::runtime_error&) {
    do_B();
} catch (const std::bad_alloc&) {
    do_B();
}
```

If you need the same exception handling in multiple locations you can put it into a function like so:

```
void handle_exception() {
    try {
        throw; // re-throw the original exception our caller caught, so we can catch and handle specific ones.
    } catch (const std::out_of_range&) {
        do_A();
    } catch (const std::invalid_argument&) {
        do_A();
    } catch (const std::runtime_error&) {
        do_B();
    } catch (const std::bad_alloc&) {
        do_B();
    }
}
```

And then, at multiple places, you can do

```
try {
    /* Stuff */
} catch (...) {
    handle_exception();
}
```

Comment: Thank you... I hoped a different solution (like catching more exceptions at once) but I think this is the best one!

Comment: @Foxel Expanded a bit on my answer to help you reduce duplicated code when multiple locations need the same exception handling.